# AngularJS Unit Test: Module 'admin.module' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, karma-jasmine

I'm testing an Angular controller using Karma and Jasmine but I can't seem to load in my module from my main class.

Here's my main class: `admin.controller.js`

```
angular.module('admin.module').controller('admin.controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.SaveChanges = function()
{
    return true;
}
}]);
```

Here's my test class: `admin.controller.tests.js`

```
describe('admin.controller tests', function () {

    beforeEach(module('admin.module'));
    var $controller = {};

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('$scope.SaveChanges', function () {
        it('Should return true', function () {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('admin.controller', { $scope: $scope });
            expect($scope.SaveChanges()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

My `karma.conf.js` file points to the following files in my project:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  '../TriAngular/scripts/angular.js',
  '../TriAngular/scripts/angular-mocks.js',
  '../TriAngular/app/admin/*.js',
  'app/admin/*.js'
],
```

The `admin.controller.js` file is inside `../TriAngular/app/admin` and my `admin.controller.test.js` is inside 'app/admin'.

I have tried to directly reference the files in my karma config file which has not worked. The full error is:

> Module 'admin.module' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to not be obviously from the exception being shown. I was missing a `angular-route.js` file which needed to be included as it looked like my admin module was dependent on it.

List of includes in my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  '../TriAngular/scripts/angular.js',
  '../TriAngular/scripts/angular-mocks.js',
  '../TriAngular/scripts/angular-route.js',
  '../TriAngular/app/admin/*.js',
  'app/admin/*.js'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
beforeEach(function(){
module('admin.module');
    }
});
```

I'm not familiar with Karma, but you also need to register your module as well, I've only ever used Jasmine with resharper so what I do to register files is;

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/app.js" />
```

At the top of the file.

Also don't forget to reference your module's dependencies as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer though it still comes up with the same error